# Deleting all channels in a server

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot that auto-sets up a server, and I was wondering how to delete all channels and categories in a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is very simple:

```js
message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
```

That should do it.

> Remember to use this in response of a message, or `message` will be undefined

Comment: Might be worth adding that this would be in response to a message. Otherwise, `message` would not be defined.

Comment: Important note: your bote should be admin / have the right to delete the channels

Comment: This returns an error:  message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function (Discord.js v14)

Answer (score 4):

**You can run a loop for every single channel in the server**

*(Categories are considered as channels too)*

```
//This goes in Client.on('ready', ...);
var server = Client.guilds.get('Your servers ID'); //Check Discord's Help For it
for (var i = 0; i < server.channels.array().length; i++) {
    server.channels.array()[i].delete();
}
```

This way all your channels and categories will get deleted everytime your bot runs.
You can move this code inside a command to delete all the channels with a command instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I use my mine to delete all channels.

```
client.on('message', message =>{
  if(message.author.id == "YourID") {
  if(message.content === "!bye") {
  message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
    }
  }
})
```