# How do I mass-delete channels on DIscord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot that manages servers, and I would like to know how to delete all channels currently in a server with a single command

Answer (score 0):

```
message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
```

Source: [Discord.js - Deleting all channels in a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201440/discord-js-deleting-all-channels-in-a-server)

Comment: I tried using this but I kept getting the response TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function

Comment: That means there is something wrong with your object. Try using a debugger or console.logging to see child properties. One of the attributes (either "message" or ".guild" or ".channels") is probably undefined. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, when I edited the comments a little bit, the error message said that Guild was undefined? How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: That means your "message" object is undefined. You are trying to use the message object when it doesn't exist. You are calling this function from the wrong place. You need to call it from the right context; ie when handling the response of a message. 

Please select my answer as the correct one if this ends up doing the trick for you :)