# "cannot acces 'message' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm getting an error from my code, the error is:

```
    let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel.id);
                                                       ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'channel' before initialization
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dasjo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\main.js:15:56)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\dasjo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\dasjo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
scord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\dasjo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\dasjo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

And my code, without the error looks like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
console.log('charging duh...')
client.once('Loading...', () => {
    console.log('Loading...');
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === `${prefix}lol`) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 13000; i++) {
            message.channel.send('<@632899988011220992>')
            
        }
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}test`) {
        let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get
        (channel.id);
        channels.forEach( channel => {  channel.delete() })
    }
        
});

client.login(token)
```

How can I let them work? (I want to delete all channels in a server.)

The [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201440/deleting-all-channels-in-a-server) doesn't work for me, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting all channels in a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201440/deleting-all-channels-in-a-server)

Comment: no whyever it doesnt answer my question, i tried it before, it dont work

Comment: What does _"dont work"_ mean? What was the error?

Comment: The Error is:                                                                                                          TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you want to access `channel.id` before `channel` was defined. Read more about this error on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init).

To delete every channel, you can use `message.guild.channels.cache.forEach`. It will iterate over every channel.

`message.guild.channels` is a [ChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager) in discord.js v12. You can use the `.cache` property to get the cache of channels. It returns a [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), so you an use the `forEach` method on that.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content === `${prefix}lol`) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 13000; i++) {
      message.channel.send('<@632899988011220992>');
    }
  } else if (message.content === `${prefix}test`) {
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
      channel.delete();
    });
  }
});
```

PS: 13000 `message.channel.send`?!

Comment: then i get the error: TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function.

Comment: There is no `message.guild.channels.forEach` in my code...