# Delete all channels (voice and text) from a server - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have just started to work with discord bots, without any previous knowledge about javascript. I've been using some tutorials on youtube to code the bots. I've also been using "slappey" and "nodemon" to code and run them in a easier way.
Now I want to make a command that deletes all voice and text channels from a server (and maybe all roles too but not necessassary) but I can't find out how to do it using this specific CLI (slappey and nodemon).

I was wondering if anyone could help me with it.

(I've tried some codes like this one: [Deleting all channels in a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201440/deleting-all-channels-in-a-server) but it didn't work)

All help is useful

Answer (score 0):

You can pull this off with a for loop. For each channel in guild, delete channel.

```
guild.channels.forEach(deleteAllChannels);
function deleteAllChannels(value, index, array) {
  index.delete();
}
```

(I don't use node.js much so my syntax might be off, I'm not 100% sure if the for loop will work.)

Comment: I've tried it like this: https://pastebin.com/3d6jDLi2 and it didn't work.

Error output: https://pastebin.com/7nBG4PnU

Comment: @hugocar2005 i edited my answer, can you try that?